# svn - unversioned already versioned?

Tags: svn

I deleted all of the files from an svn repo. I then tried to recommit the files. This was going fine until some nested folders started to chuck out this message. How do i overcome this?

> Execute: Add Error: Error while
>   performing action:
>   '/opt/lampp/htdocs/cmsv5/cms/images/breadcrumb'
>   is already under version control

Comment: What was your original intention for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete any remaining (hidden) `.svn` folders from within the directories that are giving you trouble. They'll probably exist in every single nested dir.

If that's not the problem, be sure to do a clean checkout and update before you move the files into the directory where you want to commit them. Then re-add them, and commit. Always beware of stray `.svn` folders.

Comment: Thanks, I thought .svn folders were only found in the root. Lesson learned.

Comment: Yeah. This still bites me from time to time. The `export` command can help lessen this problem in some circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

There are .svn directories still in the structure and you need to clean this up.  To do so, right click the top-level folder in question and hit `Export...`.  You will be asked to choose a directory.  Choose the same top-level folder as you right clicked on.  "Ok" the confirmation dialog and it will be un-versioned.

Comment: He's using linux or a unix. Right clicking isn't going to be the solution. Not everyone uses windows...

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that until I looked at the path, thanks for clearing that up.